# AngularJS: handling menu contexts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a menu that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see from the address bar, I'm at the `/clients` route. I need my menu to have the "Clients" item highlighted. I'm really struggling to do this. There must be a straigtforward way of handling menu state in AngularJS???

I'm using `angular-ui-router` for routing and I'm happy that it's working as expected.

Here's my code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">

  <div layout="row">
    <div flex><img src="img/logo4.png" class="logo" /></div>
  </div>



  <md-toolbar hide-gt-sm layout="row" layout-align="end center">
    <md-menu-bar>
      <md-menu>
        <md-button aria-label="Menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </md-button>

        <md-menu-content width="4" ng-model="selected">
          <div data-ng-repeat="t in ctrl.menu">
            <md-menu-item ng-hide="{{ctrl.isDefined(t.subMenus)}}">
              <md-button style="font-size:14px">{{t.name}}</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>

            <md-menu-item ng-hide="{{!ctrl.isDefined(t.subMenus)}}">
              <md-menu>
                <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">{{t.name}}</md-button>
                <md-menu-content width="3">
                  <md-menu-item ng-repeat="u in t.subMenus">
                    <md-button style="font-size:14px">{{u.name}}</md-button>
                  </md-menu-item>
                </md-menu-content>
              </md-menu>
            </md-menu-item>
          </div>
        </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>
    </md-menu-bar>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>
```

And here's the `MainCtrl` Javascript:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
  .module('eamorr')
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  function MainCtrl($scope, $meteor, $mdDialog) {
    var vm=this;

    console.log("MainCtrl");


    vm.menu = [{
      "id": "home",
      "name": "Home",
      "href": "home"
    }, {
      "id": "about",
      "name": "About",
      "href": "about"
    }, {
      "id": "areas",
      "name": "Specialty Areas",
      "href": "areas",
      "subMenus":[{
        "id:":"areaRetail",
        "name":"Retail Pharmacy",
        "href":"areas?area=retail"
      },{
        "id:":"areaHospital",
        "name":"Hospital Pharmacy",
        "href":"areas?area=hospital"
      },{
        "id:":"areaIndustrial",
        "name":"Industrial Pharmacy",
        "href":"areas?area=industrial"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "clients",
      "name": "Clients",
      "href": "clients"
    }, {
      "id": "blog",
      "name": "Blog",
      "href": "blog"
    }, {
      "id": "latest",
      "name": "Latest",
      "href": "latest"
    }];
  }


  vm.isDefined = function (thing) {
    if(typeof thing === "undefined"){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
})();
```

Can anyone make any suggestions as to how to handle the state in a clean, maintainable way?

Comment: How about creating a directive which will check the location and add class to appropriate menu?

Comment: @AnandG I'm afraid I don't know what class I should use to highlight the md-button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI-Router provides an easy way to add classes if the state matches the current state. All we have to do is use `ui-sref-active`
You can write something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctr.items" >
     <a ui-sref="{{item.href}}" ui-sref-active="active">{{item.name}}  </a>     
 </li>
```

[Highlight current selected Menu-plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gezqoj?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for this work. The plunker is excellent. I'm just going through it now. The other problem is finding out what the class for an active `<md-button>` is called... I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I think you can use md-primary to apply on button .

Comment: I ended up creating my own user-defined CSS class: `.active{
    background-color: rgba(158,158,158,0.2);
  }`   The `ui-sref-active` thing is brilliant!!! Thank you so much for telling me about it. I would have totally missed it otherwise...

Comment: I will try this with material .I will let you know if I succeed :)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller add the following line

```
$scope.state = $state;
```

> Note: Inject $state in your dependencies.

`$state.current.name` will get you the current state name with which you can change/add the classes to the target element with the help of `ng-class`

```
ng-class="{'class_name_to_highlight': state.current.name == 'client'}"
```

where `class_name_to_highlight` is the CSS class to highlight.

Comment: Hello this is very useful. Unfortunately, I don't know what the `class_name_to_highlight` is... I've searched the angular material website and can't find the correct class name (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button)

Comment: It's a user defined CSS class name, please change it with the one you have in your css file for highlighting the text/element.

Comment: OK. I'll give it a go and report back. I'd like to use the material design standard class names, rather than my own CSS.

Comment: I ended up creating my own CSS class... `.active{
    background-color: rgba(158,158,158,0.2);
  }`